# dual function not working when using several measures in a plot

Tags: qliksense

I am making a barplot with two measures both using the `dual()` function like so:

```
IF(AMOUNT>4,AMOUNT,dual(num('5','<#'),4))
```

I want the number formatting to be by measure expression so that all numbers below 5 are displayed as `"<5"` instead of their actual value.

For example, if:

```
AMOUNT = [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1] 

AMOUNT displayed in plot = [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, <5, <5, <5, <5]
```

When I use only one of the measures the plot works fine and everything is displayed correctly.
However, if I use both measures, the chart displays `"4"` (actual value) instead of `"<5"` (the measure expression).

Does anyone know how to make the plot display the measure-expression when using several measures?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how exactly you want chart suppose to look like (I understand that "AMOUNT" is a dimension but what is a measure - bar height?). Maybe you could share example chart (can be even in paint) and screenshot of data-model. Generally you should modify only dimension and set it just as:

```
=If(AMOUNT<5,'<5',AMOUNT)
```

Expression leave as it is so for example:

```
Count(Field)
Sum(Field)
```